# Why do I see the DataManager in some Xamarin apps being set up with a get?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application is set up like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public static DataManager db;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    public static DataManager DB
    {
        get
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                db = new DataManager();
            }
            return db;
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain to me the advantage of setting up the DataManager in this way vs:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
        db = new DataManager();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people do not like static global variables. They try and replace them with concrete instances of classes instead.

What they should really be doing is to create an interface for each class and use dependency injection to provide the classes. This will then allow unit testing and proper separation of concerns. Using an MVVM pattern is also a good idea.

This can be a large change though for a lot of people and is often requires a new mind-set.

Comment: What you say is true, but it is no answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

**Using First Method (Static)**

-> you can use DataManager before App object is created
it is to provide global availability in the project. 
If you need to use DataManager before the app started you use this Approach.

**Using Second Method (in Constructor)**

-> you can't use DataManager before App object is created.
Because of global Availability, It may throw null reference exception.
If any possibility of an exception in code it is not good for Application.

Answer (score 3):

Null safety is one of the important consideration, In general case, Constructor's way allows your object to be safely used if anything that attempted to use it.

In you example:

```
public static DataManager db;
```

Since `db` is declared as `public`, somebody could attempt to use it before it being assign to a new object instance.

And if there is a method called `Print()` in your DataManager Class.
Before object initialisation, imagine somebody type below code in the program:

```
  public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
        db.Print();
    }
```

When you run the program, even db hasn’t been initialising, it will still passes the compile time and you will get `NullReferenceException` error in Runtime.

Aside of that, It may depend on your strategy, in a `Convenience strategy`, you may use Constructor to create you object instances at the very beginning or you may use an `Optimisation strategy` , only create it at the point of time they are actually needed, to save the system resources.

Answer (score 1):

In case it would be a static constructor

```
public static App()
{
    db = new DataManager();
}
```

there is not much difference to the get-property sample. In the case you described someone could access the public field (ignoring the property) and get an empty DataManager, if no instance of the class was ever created, while using the property always returns a non-null object. Even more, each time a new object is created, it would create a new DataManager, overwriting the old one. So if you put it in the constructor, do it in a static constructur like shown above.

You can make the field protected to enforce using the property

```
protected static DataManager db;
```

This is called the singleton pattern, if you want to look up further information.